# Add variable value with property name in IOS

Tags: ios, loops, properties, nsarray

I have 5 property with name address1, address2, ..... , address5. Now i want to iterate through all the property and assign them some value from array as follows.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   self.address *value of i+1* = endAddress[i]; // like address1 = endAddress[0] and address2 = endAddress[1]
}
```

Ia there any way to achieve this? If yes, then how?

I googled it but unable to find a solution of adding integer with property instead found solutions to add integer with NSString.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better to use an NSMutableArray to start with rather than 5 discrete properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Key Value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) could be used for this, however the value being stored must be an Objective-C object, and not a primitive type.  So for a number this means using `NSNumber`:

```
@property NSNumber *address1;
@property NSNumber *address2;
@property NSNumber *address3;
@property NSNumber *address4;
@property NSNumber *address5;

...

for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    NSString *keyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"address%d", i + 1];
    [self setValue:@(endAddress[i])
            forKey:keyName];
}
```